# Custom numericality validation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, numbers

I needed to add a custom validation option for numericality that accepts , and . as separators and provides localized error messages, while the field itself is a string.

Answer (score 0):

I create a custom validation inside of my model, which means that I have access to the field names (average and grade_scale in this case)

```
validate :average_valid_number

def average_valid_number
    avg = average.gsub("," , ".")
    case avg
    when /\A0[xX]/
      errors.add(:average, :not_a_number)
    else
      begin
        Kernel.Float(avg)
      rescue
        errors.add(:average, :not_a_number)
      end
      if grade_scale == "CH"
        errors.add(:average, :greater_than_or_equal_to, options = {:count => 4}) if avg.to_f < 4
        errors.add(:average, :less_than_or_equal_to, options = {:count => 6}) if avg.to_f > 6                
      end
    end      
end
```